# Merge two maps to get Map<String, Set<Information>>

Tags: java, collections

How do you merge 2 maps to get a new map which maps a key to a Set.
Eg:

```
Map<String, Information> map1;
Map<String, Information> map2;
```

Now I would like to get the result as

```
Map<String, Set<Information>> resultMap;
```

Comment: can you provide an example, what you have in input and in output?

Comment: Kindly check my answer again

Answer (score 3):

Using streams:

```
Map<String, Information> map1;
Map<String, Information> map2;

Map<String, Set<Information>> result = Stream.of(map1, map2)
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do that :

```
        Map<String, Information> map1;
        Map<String, Information> map2;

        Map<String, Set<Information>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<>(map1.keySet());
        keySet.addAll(map2.keySet());

        keySet.stream()
                .forEach(t -> {
                    Set<Information> data = new HashSet<>();
                    if (map1.get(t) != null)  {
                        data.add(map1.get(t));
                    }
                    if (map2.get(t) != null)  {
                        data.add(map2.get(t));
                    }

                    resultMap.put(t, data);
                });
```

Keep in mind that this will only work the way you want when `Information` class has `overriden` equals method

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the key sets of the 2 original maps (`map1.keySet()` then `map2.keySet()`) to fill your new instance of `Map<String, Set<Information>> resultMap = new HashSet<String, Set<Information>>`, for example.

Each time you add a value, add it to the existing Set or to a brand new one when no value has already been added.

```
Optional<Set<Information>> data = Optional.of(resultMap.get(aKey1));
if (data.isPresent()) {
    data.get().add(map1.get(aKey1))
} else {
    final Set<Information> newSet = new HashSet<>();
    newSet.add(map1.get(aKey1));
    resultMap.put(aKey1, newSet);
}
```

You could also try a more functional approach using Streams.

Answer (score 0):

@Jom has already given a very good answer using stream. 
This is just another answer using streams and [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function of Maps.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

Stream.of(map1, map2).flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()).forEach(entry -> {
    resultMap.merge(entry.getKey(), Collections.singleton(entry.getValue()),
            (v1, v2) -> Stream.concat(v1.stream(), v2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
private Map<String, Set<Information>> mergeMap(Map<String, Information> map1, Map<String, Information> map2) {
    Map<String, Set<Information>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : map1.keySet()) {
        Set<Information> set;
        if(resultMap.containsKey(key))
            set = resultMap.get(key);
        else 
            set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(map1.get(key));
        resultMap.put(key, set);
    }

    for (String key : map2.keySet()) {
        Set<Information> set;
        if(resultMap.containsKey(key))
            set = resultMap.get(key);
        else
            set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(map2.get(key));
        resultMap.put(key, set);
    }

    return resultMap;
}
```

Comment: This will create Map<String, Information> and not Map<String, Set<Infomation>>